# set custom length and width NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

For my application I want to set a custom length and width for my NSWindow from within the application itself.  I have everything set up (the NSTextfields) however I'm stumped with how I should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSRect` is defined like this:

```
typedef struct _NSRect {
    NSPoint origin;
    NSSize size;
} NSRect;
```

And `NSSize` is defined like this:

```
typedef struct _NSSize {
    CGFloat width;
    CGFloat height;
} NSSize;
```

You need to convert your `NSString`s to numbers first. You can do that like this:

```
CGFloat numericalValue = [stringValue doubleValue];
```

(I don't actually remember if `CGFloat` is defined as a `float` or `double`. I'm just too lazy to look it up right now.)  Note that this will cause an exception if `stringValue` does not represent a properly formatted number.

Comment: thanks, now I got rid of the errors, now I just need to set that height and width to the window

Comment: `CGFloat` is a `float` in 32-bit and a `double` in 64-bit. But since you need to make an NSSize you will probably use `NSMakeSize` which takes floats, so try using `[customWidth floatValue]` etc.

Comment: Yep, `NSMakeSize` would be easier and more compact. I should have mentioned that in my answer. Thanks for saving me the effort of looking up `CGFloat` :-)

Answer (score 4):

You want the `setFrame:display:` or `setFrame:display:animate:` method on NSWindow.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setFrame:display:):

```
- (void)setFrame:(NSRect)windowFrame display:(BOOL)displayViews
```

**Parameters**
*windowFrame*
The frame rectangle for the window.

*displayViews*
Specifies whether the window redraws the views that need to be displayed. When YES the window sends a displayIfNeeded message down its view hierarchy, thus redrawing all views.

Comment: how do I set the length and width from this?

Comment: Serriously?  That's the whole point.  Make up an NSRect with your desired origin and size, and then send it to your window with this method.  It will change size.

Comment: That's what i tried but I got the error "incompatible types in assignment"

Comment: How are you creating the NSRect?

Comment: That's probably your problem. NSRect is s struct, not an object. You should declare it as NSRect name (note, no asterisk). The incompatible type is probably because it's expecting an NSRect and your passing in an NSRect* (a pointer to an NSRect)

Comment: All of this is within the ibaction of the window:
    
 NSString *newlen = [customlength stringValue];
 NSString *newwid = [customwidth stringValue];
 NSRect rect =[[self screen] frame];
 rect.size.height = newlen;
 rect.size.width = newwid;
//setFrame:(NSRect)rect;
// NSRect frameRect.size.height = newlen;
// NSRect frameRect.size.width = newwid;
// NSLog(newlen, newwid);

Comment: `NSString`s are not numbers. Of course the `NSRect` has no idea what to do with strings. It expects `CGFloat` values for `width` and `height`.

Comment: #1, Edit your question to add the code.  #2, why would you use strings to do the job of numbers.  Time to go back to basics, I think.

Comment: Your rush meant it took longer to sort out your problem.